# How to save new row with ID is auto increment in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.6

Hi i'm a new user with cakePHP version 2.x.x and i'm trying add new Book into table Books in Database but i can't
Please check my code below

```
class Book extends AppModel{

var $name = "Book";
var $primaryKey = 'ID';

var $validate = array();


public function vaildInput()
{
    $this->validate = array(

        // Thiet lap validate cho form
        "title" => array(

            "rule1" => array(
                "rule"      =>  "notempty",
                "message"   =>  "Không được để trống."
            ),

            "rule2" => array(
                "rule"      =>  array("minlength", 5),
                "message"   =>  "Vui lòng nhập tối thiểu 5 kí tự."
            ),
        ),

        "description" => array(
            "rule"      =>  "notempty",
            "message"   =>  "Không được để trống."
        )

    );

    if($this->validates($this->validate))
        return true;

    return false;
}}
```

And Controller

```
public function form()
{
    $this->Book->set($this->data);

    if(!$this->Book->vaildInput())
    {
        $this->set("data", "Data không hợp lệ");
    }
    else
    {
        // Every thing is ok
        if($this->request->is("post"))
        {
            if($this->Book->save($this->data))
            {
                $this->set("data", "Insert Book Success.");
            }
            else
                $this->set("data", $this->data);
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
if(!empty($data))
var_dump($data);
echo $this->form->create("Book", array("action" => ""));
echo $this->form->input('ID',array('type'=>'hidden') );
echo $this->form->input("title");
echo $this->form->input("description");
echo $this->form->end("Add");
```

with Table Books have column ID is Primary Key with Auto_Increment, so i have a question how i can save new row Book to database ? I tried but didn't success :(

Comment: If you want to save as a new id, no need of id just send all values and save it.

Comment: woa, this my mistake because case insensitive. I have use title but in database is Title.

Answer (score 0):

This my mistake because case insensitive. I have use title but in database is Title.